# Overriding application.properties for test classes

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to spring boot. I am writing my tests and added a property

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration
```

to disable my Kafka related configurations.
Now I want to write a few kafka related tests for which I want to enable the kafka auto configuration.
How to I enable the property for a bunch of kafka tests. I just want to write a couple of kafka tests so can happily add property to `@SpringBootTest(properties = [""])` annotation. But I am not getting what value should I add there?

If this is too naive please re direct to some good documentation.

Comment: Please, investigate these samples which are fully based on Spring Boot and provides some tests against embedded Kafka broker: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/samples